# Making a sub-query with sequelize to filter upcoming events using dates and times

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

who knows how to query for an upcoming event using sequelize?
I want a situation whereby once an event has started `(Event date >= today's date AND event time >= today's time)`, it's removed from the "upcoming events" column
I have tried

```
db.Event.findAll({
     where: {
        [db.Sequelize.Op.and]: [{ isPrivate: false },
            { startdate: { $gte: new Date().toLocaleDateString() } },
            { starttime: { $gt: new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB') } }
        ]
     }, 
     include: [{
       model: db.Center,
       attributes: ['id', 'name', 'location']
     }],
     order: [
       ['startdate', 'ASC'],
       ['starttime', 'ASC']
     ]
})
    .then((events) => {
     res.status(200).json({
         success: 'ok',
         data: events
    });
})
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err.message || 'Internal server error',
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work and I have been told why it doesn't work.
I need a way to filter out the time WHEN `(startdate >= new Date().toLocaleDateString())`. I have tried in vain to find out how that works. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const dateOfToday = new Date();
const timeOfToday = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');

const daysEqualToToday = db.Event.findAll({
  where: {
    startdate: { $eq: dateOfToday },
  },
  include: [{
    model: db.Center,
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'location']
  }],
  order: [
    ['startdate', 'ASC'],
    ['starttime', 'ASC']
  ]
})
  .then(events =>
    events.filter(event => event.starttime > timeOfToday));


const daysGreaterThanToday = db.Event.findAll({
  where: {
    startdate: { $gt: dateOfToday },
  },
  include: [{
    model: db.Center,
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'location']
  }],
  order: [
    ['startdate', 'ASC'],
    ['starttime', 'ASC']
  ]
});


Promise
  .all([daysEqualToToday, daysGreaterThanToday])
  .then((results) => {
    const combinedResult = [].concat(...results);
    res.status(200).json({
      success: 'ok',
      data: combinedResult
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err.message || 'Internal server error',
    });
  });
 }
```

So, I wasn't able to use a sequelize sub-query to solve my problem. I got a suggestion(not from stackoverflow), to save my dates as datetime in the database and use it to compare datetimes directly querying the database twice. I decided against it because I felt it wasn't great for user experience.

I eventually decided to go for a less than ideal solution. Make two queries to the database 
first one: make a query when the start date is the same as today's date and then filter the start time to find start times greater than today's time.

second one: make a query when the start date is greater than today's date.

I then used Promise.all to resolve both queries. Like I said, the solution is less than ideal as I make two calls to the database, but I will go with it for now. I will appreciate better ways of implementing this.